# How to change color of the selected item using material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to material ui, My objective is to change the color when we are clicking an item on it. It is showing blue color and black bprder, i want to show in a normal way like grey color without border black.
Can anyone help me in changing color while selecting the item?

Here is code:

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <NativeSelect
          name="age"
          className={classes.selectEmpty}
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "age" }}
        >
          <option value={10}>one</option>
          <option value={20}>two</option>
        </NativeSelect>
      </FormControl>
```

[Here is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-g4url)

Comment: You need to play with disabled states for Input. because that underline comes from the Input component. If you try to look into the console those classes are pseudo selectors from material ui Input component. You can override them using input props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your case best way to solve this issue is not to use NativeSelect. MaterialUI has it's own [Select Component](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/). The API is great and you can override all css classes that you want and change the UI of the component. [Here](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) is the whole component API with all the options you can use.

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <Select
      name="age"
      defaultValue={20}
      className={classes.selectEmpty}
      inputProps={{ "aria-label": "age" }}
      MenuProps={{ style: { top: "35px" } }}
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}>one</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>two</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

Comment: Hi, When i use the above Select component, it is not coming below the input field

Comment: Yeah...but you can play around with styles in menu props as I edited in my original answer:)

Comment: Thanks this is working great!. Could you please help me in my new query?

Comment: How to get the value one to show as default? Could you please assist me?

Comment: There is a defaultValue prop for Select. I edited the answer with documentation and solution